# What are these bash functions on Alma Linux 8 viewable in the environment with `env`?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alma-linux

When I run in `env` in Alma Linux 8, I get the following

```bash
BASH_FUNC_which%%=() {  ( alias;
 eval ${which_declare} ) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
}
BASH_FUNC_module%%=() {  _module_raw "$@" 2>&1
}
BASH_FUNC__module_raw%%=() {  unset _mlshdbg;
 if [ "${MODULES_SILENT_SHELL_DEBUG:-0}" = '1' ]; then
 case "$-" in 
 *v*x*)
 set +vx;
 _mlshdbg='vx'
 ;;
 *v*)
 set +v;
 _mlshdbg='v'
 ;;
 *x*)
 set +x;
 _mlshdbg='x'
 ;;
 *)
 _mlshdbg=''
 ;;
 esac;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${IFS+x}" ]; then
 _mlIFS=$IFS;
 fi;
 IFS=' ';
 for _mlv in ${MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE:-};
 do
 if [ "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv##*[!A-Za-z0-9_]}" -a "${_mlv}" = "${_mlv#[0-9]}" ]; then
 if [ -n "`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'+x}'`" ]; then
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}_modquar='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlv'}'`' ";
 fi;
 _mlrv="MODULES_RUNENV_${_mlv}";
 _mlre="${_mlre:-}${_mlv}='`eval 'echo ${'$_mlrv':-}'`' ";
 fi;
 done;
 if [ -n "${_mlre:-}" ]; then
 eval `eval ${_mlre} /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash '"$@"'`;
 else
 eval `/usr/bin/tclsh /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl bash "$@"`;
 fi;
 _mlstatus=$?;
 if [ -n "${_mlIFS+x}" ]; then
 IFS=$_mlIFS;
 else
 unset IFS;
 fi;
 unset _mlre _mlv _mlrv _mlIFS;
 if [ -n "${_mlshdbg:-}" ]; then
 set -$_mlshdbg;
 fi;
 unset _mlshdbg;
 return $_mlstatus
}
BASH_FUNC_switchml%%=() {  typeset swfound=1;
 if [ "${MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION:-0}" = '1' ]; then
 typeset swname='main';
 if [ -e /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl ]; then
 typeset swfound=0;
 unset MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION;
 fi;
 else
 typeset swname='compatibility';
 if [ -e /usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd-compat ]; then
 typeset swfound=0;
 MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION=1;
 export MODULES_USE_COMPAT_VERSION;
 fi;
 fi;
 if [ $swfound -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "Switching to Modules $swname version";
 source /usr/share/Modules/init/bash;
 else
 echo "Cannot switch to Modules $swname version, command not found";
 return 1;
 fi
}
BASH_FUNC_scl%%=() {  if [ "$1" = "load" -o "$1" = "unload" ]; then
 eval "module $@";
 else
 /usr/bin/scl "$@";
 fi
}
BASH_FUNC_ml%%=() {  module ml "$@"
}
```

All of this looks foreign to me however, what creates these functions and what do they do? Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seem to be coming from an
[environment-modules](https://modules.sourceforge.net/) package.

> a tool that simplify shell initialization and lets users easily modify their environment during the session with modulefiles.
>
> ```
> $ module load gcc/9.4
> $ which gcc
> /usr/local/gcc/9.4/linux-x86_64/bin/gcc
> ```
>
> Now we'll switch to a different version of the module
>
> ```
> $ module switch gcc gcc/10
> $ which gcc
> /usr/local/gcc/10.3/linux-x86_64/bin/gcc
> ```

The `module` command has to be a function, in order to change the running
shell.

Try uninstalling the package `environment-modules` or whatever is providing directory `/usr/share/Modules/`.
Failing that, you can unset all functions with

```bash
unset -f $(typeset -F | awk '{print $3}')
```